# Can't open remote FITS with astropy more than once

Tags: python, boto3, astropy, astronomy

I'm writing a package to handle astronomical FITS files. I want to allow files to be local or in the cloud. For local files I can `fits.getdata()` or `fits.open()` as many times as I want but on remote files, I have to close the file before I can open it again.

This is an illustrative example of the problem:

```py
>>> file
<S3Boto3StorageFile: filename.fits.fz>

>>> from astropy.io import fits                                                                                                                                                                             
>>> hdul = fits.open(file)                                                                                            
>>> hdul.info() 

Filename: filename.fits.fz
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU       8   ()      
  1  SCI           1 CompImageHDU    268   (3054, 2042)   float32   
  2  CAT           1 BinTableHDU    157   259R x 37C   [D, D, D, D, K, K, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, K, D, D]   
  3  BPM           1 CompImageHDU     10   (3054, 2042)   uint8  

>>> fits.getdata(file,header=True) 

OSError: Empty or corrupt FITS file

>>> file.close()
>>> hdul = fits.open(file)
>>> hdul.info()

Filename: filename.fits.fz
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU       8   ()      
  1  SCI           1 CompImageHDU    268   (3054, 2042)   float32   
  2  CAT           1 BinTableHDU    157   259R x 37C   [D, D, D, D, K, K, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, K, D, D]   
  3  BPM           1 CompImageHDU     10   (3054, 2042)   uint8
```

For remote files I need to do a `file.close()` before it can be opened again, whereas with local files I don't.

Currently, I have to check if the input `file` is file-like (so I close it) or a Path or `str` (when I don't close it). It feels a bit hacky to have to do this check.

If this is the intended behaviour, I was wondering why its different for local and remote files, or maybe even file-like objects and non-objects.

Comment: I suspect it has almost nothing to do with the file being "remote" in any sense, and more to do with the I/O abstractions not knowing what an `S3Boto3StorageFile` is and just doing the best it can with it (it might also have something to do with details of how that class is implemented).

Comment: Just as a rough guess, when you first called `hdul.info()` that (because of the nature of FITS) has to read the entire file to the end, so its file pointer is left at or near the end of the file. So when you try to call `fits.getdata` on the same `S3Boto3StorageFile` instance it will just resume reading from at or near the end of the file, hence empty/invalid. You would need to call `file.seek(0)` first if `S3Boto3StorageFile` supports seeking. Then you call `file.close()`. For compatibility with POSIX semantics this should not allow reopening the same file object again but apparently it does

Comment: ...which is a bit odd. It seems somehow closing it magically allows it to re-read again from the start of the file. This is what I meant by the behavior you're describing possibly being an oddity of `S3Boto3StorageFile`. Also, though I'm pretty sure the way you were using `fits.getdata` above was just for demonstration purposes, just to be clear you shouldn't be using that if you already have an open handle to the file. See e.g. the warning at the top of http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#convenience-functions

Comment: You're totally right @Iguananaut, this is illustrative not production code. There seems to be different behaviour for paths and file objects, but doing `file.seek(0)` definitely gives consistently the expected behaviour.

Comment: What package exactly does `S3Boto3StorageFile` come from?  I assume something for reading files from S3 stores but I never use that so I'm not familiar.  Maybe I could try to reproduce.  I think what you're seeing is as I guessed though, especially since `file.seek(0)` works.  When handed a file-like object with a `read()` method it will just assume to just start reading the FITS file from the current location of the stream (this makes possible, theoretically, reading multiple FITS files from a single stream).

Comment: `S3Boto3StorageFile` is from `boto3` a package for interacting with AWS S3.

Comment: It seems to actually be from [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto3.py)